# Await vs exec in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When using mongoose and creating a custom filter, should one use `exec`'s function, or is await enough?

This how both would play out

```
const locations = await Location.find(
    {loc: $nearSphere: {
            $geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: coordinates
            }})
            .exec(function (err, location) {
                 location = location.filter(async function(currentLocation){
                     return // Call google maps distance api for more accuracy
                 }); 
    });
```

Or

```
let locations = await Location.find(
    {loc: $nearSphere: {
            $geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: coordinates
            }});

 locations = locations.filter(async function(currentLocation){
     return // Call google maps distance api for more accuracy
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example the assignment `const locations = await...` is redundant.
It doesn't do anything because you are using a [callback function](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks)  in the `.exec(function(err, location))` part which returns the query result.

Your second example is using the [promise based](https://nodejs.dev/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await) `.find()` method.

Both examples are valid in mongoose. What you use - callback or promise - is up to you.
I personally prefer the promise based approach because it is much more readable when things get more complicated. Error handling is easier too.

Furthermore you could also use the `.find().then().catch()` syntax. It is basically the same as using `async/await`.