# mongoose await findById and exec() not behaving as a Promise

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

I am sure there is a simple answer to this.  I just can't seem to get my head fully around Promises.

From everything I have reading, the below code should be behaving as I expect.

From what I can gather, Post.findById should await, then the following console.log('A') should execute before console.log('B').  However that is not happening.  console.log('B') is executing before console.log('A').

It appears the await in `let parent_post = await Post.findById` is having no effect, and console.log('B') is running before console.log('B').

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong with this?

```
exports.save = async function(req, res) {

        let parent_post = await Post.findById(req.body.comment_of)
          .populate("starred_users", "name email")
          .exec(function(err,parent_post){
              console.log('A');
              console.log(parent_post);
              return parent_post;
          });

        console.log('B');
        console.log(parent_post);

       // I need to do stuff to parent_post here before returning

        return parent_post

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems that you should *either* pass a callback *or* `await` the result. Not both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose - What does the exec function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549857/mongoose-what-does-the-exec-function-do) | [Await vs exec in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59633665)

Comment: Thanks gents.  Both your answers helped.  Seems exec() is not going to work with async/await.  Need either callback or .then().  Problem is I can't find how to use .populate() with anything other than exec().  Cheers

Comment: Just don't pass a callback to `.exec()`

Comment: VLAZ, do you mean remove "function(err,parent_post){" from within the exec?  So just use exec(console.log etc..)?  If so, how do I pass parent_host into .exec()

Comment: You don't, *only* keep `.exec()` with nothing else inside the brackets. Without a callback it will return a promise-compatible object. If you `await` it, you get the result. The code `.exec(function(err,parent_post){  return parent_post; });` basically intends exactly the same anyway - you want to get `parent_post` out if it. That should be the same result as result of `await /*...*/.exec()` with no callback.

Comment: OK VLAZ..  That did it.  So I needed to keep exec() empty, and just work on parent_post after it.. of course.  Thank you.  Can you post that as an answer and I can flag it as such.  Cheers.

Comment: Post.findById(req.body.comment_of)
              .populate("starred_users", "name email")
              .exec();

            // now work on parent_post.  No need to do it inside exec().